# How can I add a random order to my article blog in Joomla 3.2?

Tags: joomla3.0

I've tried to add "random" case to com_content/helpers/query.php:

```
public static function orderbyPrimary($orderby)
{
    switch ($orderby)
    {
        case 'alpha' :
            $orderby = 'c.path, ';
            break;

        case 'ralpha' :
            $orderby = 'c.path DESC, ';
            break;

        case 'order' :
            $orderby = 'c.lft, ';
            break;

        **case 'random' :
  $orderby = 'rand()' ;
  break;**

        default :
            $orderby = '';
            break;
    }

    return $orderby;
}
```

And I added the option to the blog.xml:

```
<option value="random">RANDOM</option>
```

This didn't work for me? Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

orderByPrimary reflects on the category itself. Add

```
case 'random' :
    $orderby = 'rand()';
    break;
```

to

```
public static function orderbySecondary($orderby, $orderDate = 'created')
```

on line 63 in `com_content/helpers/query.php`
In `com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.xml` add

```
<option value="random">JGLOBAL_RANDOM</option>
```

to the

```
<field name="orderby_sec" ...>
```

(not to `orderby_pri`, this is again for ordering categories).

That should do the trick.
Remember: with the next upgrade of the **com_content** component, these hacks could be lost...